# How do I inspect a class property that has been set by overridding __set

Tags: php, netbeans, yii, xdebug

Specifically, I am using the Yii framework and it populates its models by overriding the __set method.

However, when I inspect an instance of a model class using xdebug I can't see these properties.

How can I inspect them?

Comment: Can you see them if you just print out the object to the screen?

Comment: @Anthony Sure - if I explicitly reference the property. How does that help to answer my question?

Comment: Well, that wasn't my question, exactly. I want to know if you can do a print_r of the full object variable and see the properties.  If the properties are set via a setter, chances are when you explicitly reference the property, it's retrieved via a getter, which means the property is not allowed to be accessed directly (it's either private or protected), which means, if I had to guess, that xdebug can't show you the values because it doesn't see them.  If I'm right, that's how it helps answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I also asked this on the [Yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29467-inspecting-model-properites-with-xdebug-in-netbeans/).

A useful suggestion by Luke is to set a watch on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yii's magic `__get`/`__set` overrides are meant to be an one-stop shop for component properties which can be implemented either with opaque getter/setter methods (in which case there may be nothing at all to inspect) or through behaviors. Behaviors attached to a component are stored in the `CComponent::$_m` private variable, so in this case you will have to do as Yii does: drill into `$_m` and check which behavior (if any) implements the property.

Comment: The xdebug variables listed do not include anything other than local vars and their children. Am I correct in thinking that to do this  I would have to edit the code in order to inspect a model property? I think it would be easier to just temporarily or permanently add the property to the model code

Comment: Sorry, but xdebug does show class variables just as well. Just expand $this! If it's a static property however, then you need Xdebug 2.2-dev (from github)--soon to be released.

Answer (score 0):

If Yii is using getters and setters, it means that the properties are either private or protected.  If all xdebug does is a fancy version of a `print_r`, I don't think it will see either (thought I could be wrong about protected properties).  If the Yii properties are private, xdebug wouldn't have knowledge of the property name even, so it couldn't retrieve the property by name (which would trigger the getter method).

An easy test would be to do a print_r or a vardump of the entire object to the screen (using a `<pre>` about it, if you want it to legible) and see which properties are visible and which aren't.  If you're seeing the same ones that xedebug is showing, it's because xedebug can't get to them using whatever means it uses to get object properties.

If you can see all of the properties, I may still be on the right track, but I wouldn't be able to guess the actual cause.

Comment: Xdebug shows *all* properties. Public, private and protected.

Answer (score 0):

For CActiveRecord they are set in the attributes member. Check the implementation of the parent classes for the class you are interested in.